# Google AdMob Legal Requirement with swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob, app-store, ads

I'm finally ready to publish my first app but there's something I actually want to implement but don't get how it works.
I wanna display an interstitial ads with AdMob when the app is launch. But I am lost about what I need to do in order to be 100% legal and not have my app rejected by the app store or anything else. The app is gonna be available in the us and in europe.

I saw that europe has a special policy about user consent but I cannot find anything really explaining it on the AdMob docs. the app itself doesn't collect any data so I have a really basic privacy policy explaining the app doesn't collect anything, but do I need to change it if I use Admob? Do I need to ask users to consent to something and if yes how to do so?

I just want to know what I have to do to be able to present ads with AdMob on iOS, thanks guys

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no need to change in app privacy if you use AdMob. You can go with official documentation of [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial). There is no issue from appStore rejection or anything else. You can feel free to use AdMob.